# Define a Function to Lookup IDs from a List in a Dictionary and Sum the Values

Tags: python, function, dictionary

My goal for this function is for it to output the grand total cost for an order.

I have one function that gives me a dictionary like `{'2': '150.99', '3': '99.50', '15': '5.07'}` where the first value is an ID number and the second value is the price for the item with that ID number.  So item number 3 costs 99 Dollars/Euros/Pounds/Whatever my units are and 50 cents/subunits.

Another function gives me a list of item IDs to look up like this `[2, 2, 3]` where any item ID can appear more than once to show that I am purchasing more than one of that item.  So in this example I'd be buying 2 of item 2 at 150.99 each and 1 of item 3 at 99.50.

I want to define a function that lets me pass it the dictionary of item ID: prices and the list of item IDs to lookup and it would output the total cost for all items in the list.  So for the above example it should output the value `401.48` because `(2*150.99)+99.50=401.48`.

As a test I have tried

```
test = DictionaryVariable.get('2')
print test
```

This prints the expected value (so in this example it'd be 150.99.)

However, my attempts to define a function like

```
def FindPrice(dictionary, idlist):
    price = 0.00
    for id in idlist:
        price + float(dictionary.get(id))
    return price
```

and then call it like this:

```
Prices = FindPrice(DictionaryVariable, IDListVariable)
print Prices
```

have not worked - the `dictionary.get(id)` part seems to be returning `None` (which I have tested by making it a str instead of float) so it throws an error saying "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number".  I suspect that I need to use some other method of feeding in the item IDs from my list, but I don't know what that method would be.  I am not sure why the `dictionary.get(id)` returns `None` but yet `DictionaryVariable.get('2')` gives it the value I'd expect.

EDIT:
Thanks to the helpful posts that pointed out that I was using strings in my dictionary rather than integers or floats I got this to work:

```
def FindPrice(dictionary, idlist):
    Price = sum(float(dictionary.get(x,0)) for x in idlist)
    return Price
Prices = FindPrice(DictionaryVariable, FunctionThatMakesListofIDs('FileToGetIDsFrom.xml'))
print Prices
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list [2, 2, 3] contains integers, but the keys of your dict are strings. I propose you create your dict using int keys and float values to begin with, or convert it like this:

```
>>> d = {'2': '150.99', '3': '99.50', '15': '5.07'}
>>> d = dict((int(k),float(v)) for k, v in d.iteritems())
>>> d
{2: 150.99000000000001, 3: 99.5, 15: 5.0700000000000003}
```

Comment: I think you might be on to something there - what's a good way to either make the keys in my dictionary into integers or make the IDs in my list into strings?

Comment: Ah, I see now where you show how to convert it.  I have it defined to have the int(id) from the beginning, not sure why it is a string.

Comment: You were indeed right - I really thought that I had set up my dictionary to use integers for the key but I ended up using a %s in creating the list of ids (which I then zipped into a dictionary with the price data) so they were strings.  I tidied that up and problem solved :)

Answer (score 2):

`get()` returns `None` if the item is not found, BTW you can pass a second optional argument to `get()`. So, now if the `id` is not found then that argument is returned.(pass 0 in your case)

```
>>> dic={'2': '150.99', '3': '99.50', '15': '5.07'}
>>> items= ['2', '2', '3'] 
>>> sum(float(dic.get(x,0)) for x in items)  #pass 0 to get in case id is not there
401.48
```

`help(dict.get)`:

```
get(...)
    D.get(k[,d]) -> D[k] if k in D, else d.  d defaults to None.
```

Comment: In light of what Janne Karila wrote this all makes sense now - I was asking it to look for `2` (the integer) rather than `'2'` (the string) so it was returning `None`.  Once I tidied up my code so that my dictionary file has IDs as integers and the prices as floats, it all started to come together :)

Comment: @Qanthelas better use strings as keys, because dictionary considers both `1` and `1.0` as a same key.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for other projects (because that might mess me up at some point.)  For this project, though, the item IDs are all unique integers so there's no worries there.